# How to limit prefetch_related data in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I've two tables brand and a product. each brand has multiple products.

So. I used prefetch_related to get related products for a particular brand with only a minimum product price. but the problem is when I have 2 products with the same price it selects both records so how to limit this?

```
alternatives_data = Brand.objects.filter(category__category_slug = category_slug).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('products', queryset=Product.objects.annotate(
                min_brand_price=Min('brand__products__product_price')
            ).filter(
                product_price=F('min_brand_price')
            ).order_by('product_id')))
```

i tried everything but nothing work!

Comment: You need to use slice in queryset `[0]` it usefull

Comment: no slicing does not work in this.

Comment: i give the link you see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: No, it's only working with a normal filter with prefetch_related not work.

Comment: When there are two products, how do you determine which one to use?

Comment: That's confusion I don't know how to deal with it!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a query to return multiple records with duplicata in specific columns, use the `distinct` method.
In your case, add `.distinct('price')` to the Product queryset inside the prefetch.

There is however one caveat : It is supported on PostgreSQL only.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: No, i am using mysql